# TensorFlow Object Detection API Mask-RCNN Training Causes OOM Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm trying to train a Mask-RCNN (ResNet101) model on a single GPU using the TensorFlow Object Detection API.

[This the configuration I'm using for Mask-RCNN](https://gist.github.com/tasercake/9c3bce064160827cef6d62e679b328ac).

Immediately after training starts, it takes up ~24GB of CPU RAM. At the 10 minute mark, when the first round of evaluation begins, all 32GB of my CPU RAM fill up and the process gets killed.

My dataset consists of 1 sample in the training set (i.e. 1 image) and 1 sample in the eval set. The images are 775 x 522 pixels. Each sample (image + boxes + masks) amounts to no more than 2MB on disk. I've done this to ensure that the dataset's effect on memory consumption is minimised.

I've also attempted to train a Faster RCNN model on the same dataset, and it works as expected (using 2-3 GB of CPU RAM).

[This is the configuration I'm using for Faster RCNN](https://gist.github.com/tasercake/98fa44aff219ff14e01800d59f86331e)

Why is the memory usage during the training and evaluation of Mask-RCNN so high (compared to Faster RCNN's), and what can I do to reduce it?